# Integrating C++ class into PHP using SWIG

Tags: php, c++, swig

I'm using SWIG to integrate a C++ class into PHP, but for some reason the class does not appear correctly in PHP, even though a function does appear correctly. This is SWIG 2.0.4 and PHP 5.3.6 on Mac OS X 10.5.8. Here is the code and the commands used to build the library:

```
$ cat example.i
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include "example.h"
int Example::foo(void) {
    printf("This is foo\n");
    return 0;
}
%}
%module example

class Example {
public:
    int foo(void);
};
$ cat example.h
class Example {
public:
    int foo(void);
};
$ make ehphp
/opt/local/bin/swig -c++ -php5 example.i
g++ `php-config --includes` -fPIC -c example_wrap.cpp -o example_wrap.o
g++ -dynamiclib -Wl,-flat_namespace,-U,_zend_register_resource,-U,_zend_rsrc_list_get_rsrc_type,-U,_zend_wrong_param_count,-U,_compiler_globals,-U,_zend_hash_find,-U,_gc_remove_zval_from_buffer,-U,_zend_register_long_constant,-U,_zend_get_constant,-U,__efree,-U,__emalloc,-U,_zend_error,-U,__zend_list_find,-U,_main,-U,__zend_get_parameters_array_ex,-U,_zend_register_list_destructors_ex,-U,__zval_copy_ctor_func,-U,__convert_to_string,-U,__zend_hash_add_or_update,-U,_executor_globals,-U,_zval_used_for_init,-U,_zval_is_true,-U,__object_init,-U,_php_strtolower,-U,__estrndup,-U,__object_init_ex,-U,_zend_lookup_class -o ehphp.dylib example_wrap.o
sudo cp ehphp.dylib /opt/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/ehphp.dylib
$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > var_dump(dl("ehphp.dylib"));
bool(true)
php > var_dump(function_exists("bar"));
bool(true)
php > var_dump(class_exists("Example"));
bool(false)
php >
```

Comment: +1 for a complete but minimal example. (You could use `%inline %{ %}` to simplify it to one single .i file though)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're supposed to

```
require "Example.php";
```

to get the proxy class loaded. (That `php` file is generated by SWIG.)

Comment: That PHP file merely wraps the "dl" call that I'm doing separately in php -a here.

Comment: It doesn't do just that with what I have here. Called swig on your example.i file, and the example.php file contains _way_ more than just the DLL loading. In particular, it has a `class Example`.

Comment: You're completely right; I hadn't realized that SWIG put this code in the .php file (it doesn't put anything similarly substantive there for functions). Thanks for the help!